# How to store created canvas objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I created a event that creates squares side to side for every click event on the canvas. But how can I store each square so that I can then later on for example delete the last square by pressing a square.

If it helpful this my function for created squares (I have then added an EventListener for the vent click on the canvas and then run the function).
The click Value is just an object that I have created that stores the number of clicks on the canvas. Board is my canvas access variable.

```
var x =0, y = 3;
    var createSquares = function () {
            var yTimeslength = y * clickValue.length;
            if (yTimeslength<60 ) { 
                board.fillStyle = "orange";
        var square = board.fillRect (0,yTimeslength,y,y);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can store the clickValue based on which you draw the squares in an array.

```
var x =0, y = 3, clicks = [];
var createSquares = function () {
    var yTimeslength = y * clickValue.length;
    if (yTimeslength<60 ) { 
        board.fillStyle = "orange";
        var square = board.fillRect (0,yTimeslength,y,y);
        clicks.push(clickValue);
    }
}
```

So, all the squares you drew based on the clickValue will be available in clicks array.

So, as in your said, if you want to delete a square, then based on the user click pos, you will have to determine which clickValue corresponds to the click and then remove it from the clicks array, and redraw every square again.

i have created a fiddle with your description, hope it helps.
you click on empty space, a square is drawn, if you click on a square the square is deleted.

http://jsfiddle.net/b9fssptk/4/

Comment: Okey so if I have a changing number say var number = 1 and I make it number++ everytime I run the function for adding some value into the clickValue array then the different squares would be for example: [[2], [2,3], [2,4]]?
One question: I see you have event as a parameter for you game function at the end of your program. Will this automatically give you information based on the event if your for example write event.clientX?

Comment: One more quick question: the canvascontext parameter is that an inbuilt function within the javascript language that gets the canvas context without having to use the getcontext(); function itself?

Comment: i am passing the context to the functions via the canvasContext parameter.  i could have used the global context variable, but sometimes you might have more than one canvas elements, and corresponding contexts, so it has become a practice for me to pass context as parameters to functions

Comment: whenever you map a function to eventListener, by default the first parameter that will be passed is the event information.  so, you can get event.clientX from that.

Comment: i don't understand the clickValue array part.  i am assuming that 2 is a square, 3 is square and so on.  If so, then clickValues is the array which is storing all the info about the squares, and you would not need another array.

Comment: But isn't there a more ambigous answer that isn't based on my clickValues? Here it registers the rectangle to the clickValue and then when I click it check which clickValue it is and removes and clickValue from the click array. But what if I just wanted to store a simple: fillRect(....) into an array and then be able to acces that Rects properties (x,y,width,height) by saying squareArrays[0]?

Comment: You cannot store the `fillRect()`.  `fillRect` is a method of the canvas context object which does a particular action
. 
You will have to store the properties which you feed to the `fillRect(...)` method, for later retrieval.

Comment: Oh okey. Could you then explain a bit more how your code works? I do not really understand it so well since I have to back and forth all the time with all the variables when reading it. :) It is mostly the parts in the update function the deletions the clicks and mostly the "pt". Would be very helpful

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with comments, check it out, and if you have any more questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use ready-made engines with support for interactivity and the object model.

For example [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/) or [PIXI.JS](http://pixijs.github.io/examples/index.html?s=demos&f=dragging.js&title=Dragging) or [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) or other..